# How to display an image with an anchor tag in a jqGrid subgrid column

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a subgrid column which has the code below inside `subGridRowExpanded:`:

```
{ name: 'applytoall', index: 'applytoall',width: 44,
formatter:'showlink',
formatoptions:{baseLinkUrl:'mylink', 
idName:'myId', addParam:'&mainGridId='+rowId}}
```

As you can see from code above, when a user clicks on a row in the main grid and several rows open up for the sub grid, I want to show a link in each row of the subgrid and the link should contain an ID of the parent grid as well (`&mainGridId='+rowId`) in this case.

However, now instead of a link Id like an image with an anchor tag and everything else to behave the same way!

I found that a custom formatter can do this in such a way:

```
{ name: 'mycolname', index: 'mycolname',width: 44,formatter:some}

function some (cellvalue, options, rowObject)
{
   return "<a href=mylink?"
    +"myId="+cellalue.rowId+"&mainGridId="+(what should go here?)
    +"><img src='img/modify.gif'></a>"
}
```

**Question**

What should I put in `what should go here` so that I can get the `ID` of the row in the parentGrid.

If there is a better way to accomplish this, I'm all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correct you should just define `function some` *inside of* `subGridRowExpanded` callback. In the case the function `some` can access all variables defined in outer scope. The callback function `subGridRowExpanded` has `rowId` as the second parameter and you can just use it.